# openfire error with no answers

Tags: java, linux, openfire

I am running openfire server as a basis for my chat server, but i am not happy with the robustness of the openfire, it seems to be having lot of java errors,

java expert people who i talked to says that its all coding errors, that java exceptions hasn't handle correctly. Just want to know from a java expert is following errors are really java programming problem or a my server or settings problem.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.util.FastArrayList.get(FastArrayList.java:475)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:184)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDriver.connect(ProxoolDriver.java:89)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider.getConnection(DefaultConnectionProvider.java:86)
at org.jivesoftware.database.DbConnectionManager.getConnection(DbConnectionManager.java:124)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PresenceManagerImpl.userUnavailable(PresenceManagerImpl.java:280)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:168)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:135)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:199)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.handle(PresenceRouter.java:149)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.route(PresenceRouter.java:85)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:84)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager$ClientSessionListener.onConnectionClose(SessionManager.java:1164)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.VirtualConnection.notifyCloseListeners(VirtualConnection.java:214)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.VirtualConnection.close(VirtualConnection.java:190)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession$HttpVirtualConnection.systemShutdown(HttpSession.java:1008)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.LocalRoutingTable.stop(LocalRoutingTable.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.stop(RoutingTableImpl.java:857)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.shutdownServer(XMPPServer.java:948)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.access$700(XMPPServer.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer$ShutdownHookThread.run(XMPPServer.java:898)
2012.11.24 05:50:37 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - Problem
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:235)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDriver.connect(ProxoolDriver.java:89)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider.getConnection(DefaultConnectionProvider.java:86)
at org.jivesoftware.database.DbConnectionManager.getConnection(DbConnectionManager.java:124)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PresenceManagerImpl.userUnavailable(PresenceManagerImpl.java:280)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:168)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:135)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateHandler.java:199)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.handle(PresenceRouter.java:149)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.route(PresenceRouter.java:85)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:84)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager$ClientSessionListener.onConnectionClose(SessionManager.java:1164)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.VirtualConnection.notifyCloseListeners(VirtualConnection.java:214)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.VirtualConnection.close(VirtualConnection.java:190)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession$HttpVirtualConnection.systemShutdown(HttpSession.java:1008)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.LocalRoutingTable.stop(LocalRoutingTable.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.stop(RoutingTableImpl.java:857)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.shutdownServer(XMPPServer.java:948)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer.access$700(XMPPServer.java:146)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer$ShutdownHookThread.run(XMPPServer.java:898)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either a problem with the parameters you are (or aren't) passing to your database driver - or possibly a bug in the database driver itself.  My guess is that you aren't passing in required properties in your DB connection string.

It is certainly not a problem with openfire itself - we have used openfire for many years now, and it is an exceptional piece of software.

Comment: i am not doing anything fancy, i use mysql db and use ofproperty in the table to define like this below

Comment: jdbcProvider.driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider.co...  jdbc:mysql://localhost/lxx_chat?user=lxx&amp;pas...  
jdbcAuthProvider.passwordSQL  SELECT session_id FROM lxx_main.user WHERE user_i...

Comment: jdbcAuthProvider.passwordType  plain
jdbcUserProvider.loadUserSQL  SELECT name,mail FROM lxx_main.user WHERE user_id...
jdbcUserProvider.userCountSQL  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lxx_main.user
jdbcUserProvider.allUsersSQL  SELECT user_id FROM lxx_main.user
jdbcUserProvider.searchSQL  SELECT user_id FROM lxx_main.user WHERE
jdbcUserProvider.usernameField  user_id
jdbcUserProvider.nameField  name
jdbcUserProvider.emailField  email
jdbcProvider.connectionString  jdbc:mysql://localhost/lxx_chat?user=lxx&passwor...

Comment: Get rid of the connection pool (see org.logicalcobwebs entries in the stack trace).  There's nothing in that stack trace that indicates that the MySQL driver is even getting loaded.  This is absolutely a problem with the environment, not with OpenFire.

Comment: what do you mean by "connection pool" i am not sure how to get rid of that , is it a java setting or a openfire setting ?